# debounce and react window resize this reference issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, this, lodash

I am using `react` and lodash's `debounce` method. The issue I am having is updating state when the user resizes the window.

The issue I am having is that `this` is referring to the `window` as opposed to the component when the user resizes the window in this function:

`window.addEventListener('resize', this.delayedCallback)`

I have tried setting `const that = this` etc. but cannot get the correct scope. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

See code below:

```
class Card extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      cardElWidth: null
    }
    this.delayedCallback = debounce(this.setCardWidth, 1000);
    this.CardEl = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.setCardWidth()
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.delayedCallback)
  }

  setPlayerCardWidth() {
    this.setState({
      cardElWidth: this.CardEl.current.offsetWidth
    })
  } ... rest of code
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind the `setCardWidth` method to `this` in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    cardElWidth: null
  }
  this.setCardWidth = this.setCardWidth.bind(this)
  this.delayedCallback = debounce(this.setCardWidth, 1000)
  this.CardEl = React.createRef()
}
```

Or even shorter by binding directly in the debounce expression:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    cardElWidth: null
  }
  this.delayedCallback = debounce(this.setCardWidth.bind(this), 1000)
  this.CardEl = React.createRef()
}
```

Instead of using bind in the constructor, you can convert the `setCardWidth` to a class property, and use an arrow function to automatically bind to `this`.

**Note:** this requires babel's [plugin-proposal-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties).

```
setPlayerCardWidth = () => {
  this.setState({
    cardElWidth: this.CardEl.current.offsetWidth
  })
}
```

If you use class properties, you can remove the constructor as well:

```
class Card extends Component {
  state = {
    cardElWidth: null
  }

  CardEl = React.createRef()

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setCardWidth()
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.delayedCallback)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.delayedCallback)
  }

  delayedCallback = debounce(this.setCardWidth, 1000)

  setPlayerCardWidth = () => {
    this.setState({
      cardElWidth: this.CardEl.current.offsetWidth
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: lovely, that is the one! cheers for that! will give you the green tick when I can. I knew that too :-D

Comment: What method are you going to use?

Comment: the arrow function one, don't ask me why, for some reason I prefer that than binding in the constructor

Comment: I prefer that one as well. It's cleaner, and most of the time you can completely remove the constructor (see example in the code).